# Require.js & Marionette: defining includes when extending classes

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I'm working on a project using Require.js, Backbone and Marionette, and the `define/function` calls at the top of my files are getting a bit ludicrous.  I'd like to find a way to move the "includes" out of the topmost `define` block, and into the `extend` where the are relevant.

So my structure roughly looks like this:

```
define(['underscore','jquery','handlebars','someTemplate','someModel',etc...], function(_,$,Handlebars,template,model,etc...){
  var someView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // code here
  });
  return someView;
});
```

So as I add more views to the file, that `define` list gets really, really, long.  I've tried doing something like:

```
var someView = define(['someTemplate','someModel'], function(template, model){
  return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    // code here
  });
]);
```

But then `someView` is undefined when I call it later.  Am I doing this wrong, or is it not possible?

Comment: You can try the (sugar)[http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar] syntax.This way you dont have worry about matching the arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should split your modules. Having a really long list of dependencies is a sign that your module does to much. Most of the time all view need is model or collection and maybe some subViews and the global eventbus.

Also think about the need to require jQuery,Backbone etc. This are stuff that you will need in most of your modules, its easier to combine them in one file and load them in the first place. There is no much advantage to require this files, all it does is cluttering your define section with a lot of boilerplate.

The define call btw. does not return anything thats why `someView` is undefined in example. If you really wanna go with this solution you have to use `require` when you use `someView` later on. But even then its much cleaner to put `someView` in its own module file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use your require.js config file dependencies shim to aggregate your "common" or needed
modules into one namespace:

```
shim: {
       marionette: {
            deps: ["backbone", "json2", "bootstrap", "backboneRpc"],
            exports: 'Marionette'
        },

        flot_pie: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'charting', 'flot_resize'],
            exports: '$.plot'
        },
  }
```

so now you can call all you need like this:

```
define([
    'marionette',
    'flot_pie'
],

function(Marionette, graph) {
```